# How to use localStorage with numbers

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am confused with `localStorage` and how to use it with numbers and `parseInt()`.

For example, I have a 'hiScore' variable and a 'score' variable. I want to have the `hiScore` variable in my `localStorage`

localStorage takes a string variable so I have to turn it into a number with `parseInt()`

All my variables have already been setup without localStorage so I was wondering what would be the best way to now add localStorage.

I couldn't understand the documentation on mozilla or W3schools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this example:

```
localStorage.setItem("score", 123.465); //Set value
var score = localStorage.getItem("score"); ///Get value as string

//Convert
var score1 = parseInt(score)//Returns 123
var score2 = parseFloat(score)//Returns 123.465
console.log(score1,score2);
```

When you fetch value from `localStorage`, it is returned as string. Before using them into calculations you need to convert them into numbers by using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Answer (score 4):

One way to preserve variable types is by using a combination of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). For instance if you have an object with multiple variable types:

```
var info = {
   name: 'Bob',
   age: 23,
   isAdmin: true
};
```

You would save it to localStorage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('memberInfo', JSON.stringify(info));
```

And read it back using

```
var info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberInfo'));
```

Comment: Whats smaller bite wise, this or `parseInt/parseFloat`